# How to join data in Google Sheet to Metabase to create dashboard?

Tags: sql, business-intelligence, metabase

My company uses the metabase for data analysis. The data I need to build the dashboard on the metabase is divided into 2, part of the data is retrieved from the SQL querying on the metabase and the other part is using google sheets as manual data. How can I join the data of the metabase and google sheet to create the dashboard on the metabase.

For example:

1. The data I need to build the dashboard on the metabase:

Name     Age    Adress         Salary

Smith     25    Evans Mills    $9000

2. The data is retrieved from the SQL querying on the metabase:

Name      Age    Adress

Smith     25     Evans Mills

3. Manual data on google sheets:

Salary

$9000

Comment: Is there any column to join each employee record to his salary ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding of metabase, one of its limit is that it can not run queries across different databases.

However, I have helped our customer solve similar problems like yours. The software architecture is like this:

- Metabase -> [Presto SQL/Trino](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/googlesheets.html) -> different database and different data source

In this design:

1. Metabase handles the dashboard part of work.
2. Trino handles the joining across different data sources.

Note: In our customer's case, the integration really requires certain programming work. It is not a quite trivial job.